# Passing array as function parameters in PHP7.0

Tags: php-7

I have a function as follows:

```
/**
 * @param \string[] ...$whitelist
 * @return Array
 */
public function whitelist(string ...$whitelist): Array
{
    // code
}
```

How can I pass an array (e.g $arr = [$val1, $val2, ...]) to the function?

Note that I cannot change the function structure because it belongs to a third party class I am using in my code.

Comment: Thanks for the note. :)

Comment: Hey Hamid, I edited my answer, please check it out. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/**
 * @param \string[] ...$whitelist
 * @return Array
 */
public function whitelist(string ...$whitelist): Array
{
    // code
}
```

You pass the arguments by separating them by comma, meaning the **whitelist** function takes n number of arguments. You are using the splat operator (https://lornajane.net/posts/2014/php-5-6-and-the-splat-operator). So, in your case it may be something like:

```
whitelist(...['Item 1', 'Item 2', 'Item 3']);
```